# XSLT: Reading a param that's an xml document passed as a string

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I have ran into an issue with another engineer. Being a new engineer, I have to figure out the solution to this, but I haven't been able to. Any help would be appreciated, the closest thing I've found is [Chunk string with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768718/chunk-string-with-xslt) but is still not quite there. I'm only able to use XSL v1.0.

A parameter is passed to my stylesheet as a giant string. It originally came from an XML Document. The string looks something like this.

With `<xsl:value-of select="$servers"/>` where `$servers` is the param for the string passed to me. The string looks like this:

`<license><active_servers><server><name>MIKE</name><capacity>18</capacity><status>0</status><expiration></expiration><left>0</left><comment></comment></server><server><name>Susie</name><capacity>0</capacity><status>1</status><expiration>2014-07-04T00:00:00Z</expiration><left>5238568</left><comment></comment></server><server><name>Zoe</name><capacity>5000</capacity><status>1</status><expiration></expiration><left>0</left><comment></comment></server></active_servers></license>`

This is a section of the xml data passed as a param to the stylesheet. The actual document is 300 or so lines of data. The only distinctive thing that separates these "nodes" are the `<server>` and `</server>`. Is there a way to pull data out of this if it's a really big string?

Say, for example. I need to find "Zoe" and see if she has a "expiration", if she doesn't, I need her "status". So Zoe will display "1" for status since she doesn't have expiration. While MIKE will display "0" and Susie will display 2014-07-04T00:00:00Z.

I have looked all over google and stack overflow for finding a solution to parsing/reading a giant string. But I haven't come to a solution close enough where I can make it work. As of right now, I'm stuck having no working copy, and 2 days into research without getting anywhere.

Comment: A string is not XMl and cannot be parsed as XML. Is there no way you could pass a *path* to an actual XML document as the parameter?

Comment: I emailed the other engineer 4 days ago who is across the world, but haven't heard back. So I take it, this is the way he wants it. I thought maybe I missed something that would be able to read a string like that. I know I can test for a string for a certain key word, like MIKE or Zoe, but I don't think I can test for the data after the keyword, am I correct?

Comment: You can parse the string *as string*, using the string functions provided by XSLT 1.0 - which would be quite tedious and error-prone. You should really strive to process the input *as XML* - which means either (1) accessing the original data in an XML file; or (2) doing two transformations in series, with the first transformation saving the parameter to a file with a known path, and the second transformation reading from that file.

Comment: Your first solution as sending param as a XML Document with original data being the solution I had in mind. I'll talk to the engineer some more to see if I can change his mind. Thanks for your help and reassurance that I was on the right track! Could you post an answer with that and I'll mark it as answered and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is not XML and cannot be parsed *as XML*. You could of course parse the string *as string*, using the string functions provided by XSLT 1.0 - which would be quite tedious and error-prone.

If possible, pass a **path** to an actual XML document as the parameter. Alternatively, call two transformations in series, with the first transformation saving the parameter to a file with a known path, and the second transformation reading from that file.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512924/3016153

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to parse a string as XML, as @michael.hor257k correctly observed in the accepted answer, but there *is* a way to treat your string as a node-set by loading it as an embedded document. That is possible using the [data URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) with the `document()` function. [XSLT 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) warns, however, that this is implementation dependent (the processor is not required to support any uri scheme). I tested this with XSLT 1.0 processors such as Xalan and Saxon 6 and it worked.

The solution is to append your string to the data URI scheme `data:text/xml` separated by a comma. You can then pass this string to your `document()` function and it will parse it as an XML file:

```
document(concat('data:text/xml,',$servers))
```

You can then apply any templates to the node-set.

Here is a stylesheet with a `$servers` parameter which should receive your string containing XML data. It will parse the string, transform the nodes in templates, and generate a XML output with some data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="servers"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat('data:text/xml,',$servers))/license"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="license">
        <results>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- server without expiration - get status -->
    <xsl:template match="server[not(string(expiration))]">
        <server name="{name}" status="{status}" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- server with expiration - get expiration -->
    <xsl:template match="server">
        <server name="{name}" expiration="{expiration}" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you run this with any source, and your data passed as a parameter you get:

```
<results>
   <server name="MIKE" status="0"/>
   <server name="Susie" expiration="2014-07-04T00:00:00Z"/>
   <server name="Zoe" status="1"/>
</results>
```

**UPDATE**: this feature also depends on parser support for data-uris. I wasn't aware of that since my XML environment has that support, so changing different XSLT processors didn't make any difference. I used Oxygen XML Editor 15.2, in a Mac OS X environment. I will update this information when I discover exactly which parser it is using.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, however I cannot reproduce your success on any processor. I get a "Malformed URL" warning using both Saxon and Xalan. Could you correct the example here: http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8r

Comment: @michael.hor257k It seems that it depends on data-uri support by the parser as well. It works in Oxygen XML Editor 15.2 (and command line environment, which shares the same configuration), but I wasn't able to get it to work with a standard Java 8 TraX implementation yet.