# how to pass dynamically created xml in XsltArgumentList msxsl

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, msxsl

I am in a fix here where I have to pass the dynamically created xml in C# code to be passed to xslt as param and then get the values from it.

following is the sample xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="Keys"></xsl:param>  

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MyKey>MYNODE</MyKey>
    <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($Keys)/Keys/Item/Header"/> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then from the code in C# I call Transform method

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load("sheet.xslt");

XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();

XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
// populate as needed e.g.
doc1.LoadXml("<Keys><Item><Header>fooHeader</Header></Item></Keys>");

xsltArgs.AddParam("Keys", "", doc1.InnerXml.ToString());

// pass xsltArgs as second argument to Transform method

proc.Transform(someInput, xsltArgs, someOutput);
```

Here I am not able to get the value for MYNODE in results
Thanks

Comment: What result do you have ?

Comment: Comes out blank for the value as it adds &lt; and &gt; instead of > and <

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT: Reading a param that's an xml document passed as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767097/xslt-reading-a-param-thats-an-xml-document-passed-as-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here. Firstly how you pass the parameters

```
xsltArgs.AddParam("doc1", "", doc1);
```

But in your XSLT you have it named "Keys"

```
<xsl:param name="Keys"></xsl:param>
```

Therefore you need to change your C# code

```
xsltArgs.AddParam("Keys", "", doc1);
```

There is also a problem with your XSLT.

```
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($Keys)/Keys/item/header"/>
```

XML is case-sensitive. Your XML contains "Item", but XSLT is looking for "item". It should be these

```
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($Keys)/Keys/Item/Header"/>
```

Infact, I don't think you need node-set here. Try this too

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Keys/Keys/Item/Header"/>
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($Keys)/Keys/Item/Header"/>              
gives me blank result

<xsl:value-of select="$Keys/Keys/Item/Header"/>
gives an error that Expression should evaluate to node set

Thanks

Comment: In your question you have changed the adding of the parameter to  `xsltArgs.AddParam("Keys", "", doc1.InnerXml.ToString());`. Can you try changing it back to just `xsltArgs.AddParam("Keys", "", doc1);`?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have built a document with

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
// populate as needed e.g.
doc1.LoadXml("<Keys><Item><Header>fooHeader</Header></Item></Keys>");
```

you should pass that document in as the parameter value doing

```
xsltArgs.AddParam("Keys", "", doc1);
```

Then you should be able to use that parameter as in

```
<xsl:param name="Keys"></xsl:param>  

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MyKey>MYNODE</MyKey>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Keys/Keys/Item/Header"/> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Complete example, C# is

```
        XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
        proc.Load("../../XSLTFile1.xslt");

        XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();

        XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        // populate as needed e.g.
        doc1.LoadXml("<Keys><Item><Header>fooHeader</Header></Item></Keys>");

        xsltArgs.AddParam("Keys", "", doc1);

        proc.Transform(new XmlDocument(), xsltArgs, Console.Out);
```

XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="Keys"></xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MyKey>MYNODE</MyKey>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Keys/Keys/Item/Header"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output to the console is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?><MyKey xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft
-com:xslt">MYNODE</MyKey>fooHeader
```