# mapping a string containing xml in BizTalk

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an xml document with a node that may optionally contain a string of escaped xml. I'd like to be able to transform that content using xsl in a BizTalk map. Any suggestion how?

I've tried:

- msxsl:node-set(string). This creates a nameless single node with no content.
- The document() function using a url prefix of 'data:text/xml' as suggested by helderdarocha [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767097/xslt-reading-a-param-thats-an-xml-document-passed-as-a-string).
- for-each selecting the text() of the node containing the string
- using xpath() in an orchestration to extract the string then make a multipart message. It won't let me use an xmlDocument message as one of the messages in a multipart message transform.

Do I have to use a C# helper assembly to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I have tackled a similar issue in a project, where I have a series of 2 mappings (both native xslt).

The first map will map your input document to an intermediate format. This format has one "any" node (instead of the escaped XML node), where eventually, I put in the unescaped XML. I unescape using a C# extension object.

The C# code could just be a wrapper for `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`

In the second mapping, you can map using plain XPath.

**Example Input message:**

```
<root>
  <someNode>blabla</someNode>
  <any>&lt;root2&gt;&lt;myValue&gt;escapedXml&lt;/myValue&gt;&lt;/root2&gt;</any>
</root>
```

**Intermediate format:**

```
<root>
  <someNode>blabla</someNode>
  <any>
    <root2>
      <myValue>escapedXml</myValue>
    </root2>
  </any>
</root>
```

In your second mapping, you could use XPaths like `/root/any/root2/myValue/text()` without any issue.

**Important Note**:

If you need to do XSD validation against this intermediate format, this is a good way to do this as well. You would just need to create the appropriate intermediate XSD according to your needs. In my case this was needed, so I had to validate this unescaped format using a receive pipeline execution in an orchestration.

Comment: I'm doing almost exactly this. I extract the string using xpath() then load it to an xmlDocument and assign it to an xmlDocument message. You cannot map a message with the xmlDocument type but you can dynamically call a map using the transform() method and pass it a multi-part message. I can then combine and manipulate how I like in the transform step.