# how to loop through an element containing encoded xml in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a node in a schema which contains encoded xml.

Once parsed in my xslt, I need to loop through it and do what I have to do mapping-wise.

Looking for pointers on how this should be done, just now I have

```
 <xsl:value-of select="*xpath to the encoded xml/text()*" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

But I'm not sure if I should put this into a variable, could I even loop through it if it was in a variable?

I'm thinking of mapping the encoded xml element to a schema of it's own and dealing with it there.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently tried to answer a similar question here: [mapping a string containing xml in BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946155/mapping-a-string-containing-xml-in-biztalk/35950355#35950355)

It involves two mappings with an intermediate format in between:

**Example Input message:**

```
<root>
  <someNode>blabla</someNode>
  <any>&lt;root2&gt;&lt;myValue&gt;escapedXml&lt;/myValue&gt;&lt;/root2&gt;</any>
</root>
```

You can map this message to an intermediate format, where you unescape the escaped XML in your input message into its own schema.
You can unescape the string using `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` for example.

**Example intermediate format:**

```
<root>
  <someNode>blabla</someNode>
  <any>
    <root2>
      <myValue>escapedXml</myValue>
    </root2>
  </any>
</root>
```

Having a separate schema supporting all possibilities of the escaped XML, will allow you to validate the incoming message easily and will give you a better visual representation.

In a second mapping, where you use the intermediate format as input, you can then map towards your final destination schema, using either the BizTalk mapper or, like **real** BizTalkers do, plain XSLT ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this - going with a c# utility to decode, then use 2 xslt maps for the rest

Comment: Just to note, you shouldn't have to use HtmlDecode.  It would be "more correct" to read the escaped content using an Xml API to read the content as a string, then load, then append the new node tree.