# escaped XML in BizTalk message

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a BizTalk message with a node called cParams which I want to populate with a bit of XML I have converted to a string (below):

```
<ds>
  <caseid>1</caseid>
  <d1_title>MRS</d1_title>
</ds>
```

Rather than include the string as is above, it appears as the following in the orchestration debugger:

```
<ns0:nws_update_case xmlns:ns0="http://xxxxx/xxxe/v1-0">
  <cToken>xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx</cToken>
  <cParams>&lt;ds&gt;&lt;caseid&gt;1&lt;/caseid&gt;&lt;d1_title&gt;MRS&lt;/d1_title&gt;&lt;/ds&gt;</cParams>
</ns0:nws_update_case>
```

I have tried to replace the character, and also tried to insert it as the message before it was converted to a string (msg.InnerXML) but it always shows as escaped.  Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I believe you have some typos in your message. The starting node of your cParams is invalid. I am also missing something after ' it appears as the following in the orchestration debugger:'. Could you check pease?

Comment: sorry, changed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered a similar question right here:
[mapping a string containing xml in BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946155/mapping-a-string-containing-xml-in-biztalk/35950355#35950355)

Using XSLT for your mapping, you could create a BTM file mapping `ds` to `nws_update_case`.

In your XSLT, you can use a .NET extension object to wrap around `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` to decode the XML as XML instead of "escaped XML".