# BizTalk 2013r2 - C# String Replace in Expression Editor

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm currently using an expression editor to build an XML payload within my orchestration, but I need to swap out any ampersands for the XML based escape character (&).

The unmodified XML is;

```
<value>" + StudentCanonical(Student_Feed.StudentCanonicalProperty.school_name) + @"</value>
```

I've tried adding the below, but I get an 'illegal dotted name' error on the .Replace method;

```
<value>" + StudentCanonical(Student_Feed.StudentCanonicalProperty.school_name).Replace("&","&amp;") + @"</value>
```

Note; StudentCanonicalProperty.school_name) is a promoted property referenced from another class (it's a directly received message).

I believe this may be related to the field being Promoted and not Distinguished.
If this is the case, can I make the field both distinguished AND promoted, or is there an alternate approach?

Thanks

Comment: Just guessing but moving the `Replace` inside could work as you expect: `StudentCanonical(Student_Feed.StudentCanonicalProperty.school_name.Replace("&","&amp;"))`

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it seems to make the editor think this should be a property field within the referenced message (identifier 'Replace' does not exist in 'Student_Feed.StudentCanonicalPropety.school_name)

Comment: Note: Rather than using string replace it's probably better to use something for handling all special characters (e.g. as you'll also have `<` and `>` to deal with); e.g. `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35950355/361842

Comment: Cheers John, that's a good shout - I could potentially build this payload in an extensuion .dll and call the method to return the payload here in the expression.